# Detect real end of the for () loop in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, parsing, loops, for-loop

I'm going to show in my app a sort of UIActivityIndicatorView while parsing several JSON objects, inside a for () loop. I can't figure WHERE I must place the [UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating] and [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] to show the real END of parsing (at the end of the complete for () loop). This is the simplified code:

```
- (void)parseMethod {

// other stuff

        for (int i=0; i < [arrayJSON count]; i++) {

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"http://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/%@",[arrayJSON objectAtIndex:i]]];

            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

                NSMutableDictionary *arrayMain = [JSON objectForKey:@"main"];
                NSMutableDictionary *arrayMain2 = [JSON objectForKey:@"main2"];
                [arrayA1 addObject:[arrayMain valueForKey:@"A1"]];
                [arrayA2 addObject:[arrayWind valueForKey:@"A2"]];

                // HERE FINISH PARSING AFJSONREQUESTOPERATION
                // IF I PUT HERE [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] IT SHOWS AT THE END OF FIRST for () LOOP

                [table reloadData];
                [table scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES]
            }
                                                                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                                            NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
                                                                        }];
            [operation start];
            // HERE START PARSING AFJSONREQUESTOPERATION
            [UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating] 
        }

    // HERE FINISH THE for () LOOP ??
    // IF I PUT HERE [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] IT SHOWS AGAIN AT THE END OF FIRST for () LOOP

} 

    // HERE FINISH THE parseMethod ??
    // IF I PUT HERE [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] IT SHOWS AGAIN AT THE END OF FIRST for () LOOP

    }
```

As u can see, I can't find the true place to put [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating], 'cos everywhere it stop at the end of the FIRST parsing (first for () loop): so, there is a way to WAIT the complete for () loop to call [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] (or another method) AFTER the ENTIRE cycle? Thanks!

**ALTERNATIVE**
Maybe the parsing is so fast that I can't see the UIActivityIndicatorView appearing and loading? In this case, WHERE I must put a sort of timer (or the sleep(unsigned int)) to wait a few seconds before it disappear?

Comment: I suggest you to look NSOperationQueue usage with AFJSONRequestOperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to

1. Simplify the code so that is obvious what is being done there (declaring the blocks beforehand)
2. Count how many requests are running and perform the global actions only when all the requests are completed.

```
typedef void (^AFJSONSuccessBlock) (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON);
typedef void (^AFJSONFailureBlock) (NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON);
```

```
[UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];

__block int numRequests = [arrayJSON count];

AFJSONSuccessBlock onSuccess = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {   
    [...]

    numRequests--;

    if (numRequests == 0) {
        [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }
};

AFJSONFailureBlock onFailure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    [...]

    numRequests--;

    if (numRequests == 0) {
        [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    }
};

for (NSString* jsonPath in arrayJSON) {
    NSString* absolutePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://WWW.REMOTESERVERWITHJSONSOURCE.NET/%@", jsonPath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:absolutePath];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
    operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                success:onSuccess
                                                                failure:onFailure];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: Absolutely elegant! Thank you very much, this is the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the requests you are making in your loop are asynchronous, so your loop doesn't hang around for them to complete, it just fires off each one in quick succession and your block of code to load your arrays is executed once the data is received.

You could use a counter in your block that gets incremented every time a  block finishes and then once the counter matches your `[arrayJSON count]` you know when to stop the animation. Just remember to use `__block` storage

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Answer (score 0):

I would generally say that if you are unable to determine where a loop ends in your code that's an indication your code is to convoluted. Your for-loop ends just before the else statement I think. To find out you can simply click the starting bracket and XCode (if that's what you're using) will highlight the code-block...

Comment: Oh yes @nickfalk, I know that, but if I put [UIActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating] before the else statement it stops WHILE the for () loop is still loading, this is the problem...

Comment: Wouldn't you still end the animation AFTER the completion of the loop (when all JSON's are fetched?) but start the animation BEFORE the loop? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Exactly, this scheme: parseMethod -> start animation -> FOR () LOOP -> .... COMPLETE FOR () LOOP AND ALL JSON'S FETCHED -> stop animation

Comment: I think you've gotten the answer from one of the other guys. Simply add a counter at the block completion and call the stop animation whenever this counter reaches the right number == [arrayJSON count].

Comment: Yes, I have seen, I hoped it was simpler! :)